# Get nullpointerexception while inflating in custom adapter of RecyclerView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

This is onCreateViewHolder of my adapter :

```
    @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    try
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faviorate_video_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return  null ;
    }

}
```

and this line throw NullPointException :

```
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faviorate_video_item, parent, false);
```

I debugged function but nothing was null  , so I dont understand what causes problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error line I guess it can be :

1. your item layout
2. your data

and if one of these ( most probably first one  ) causes problem you may get irrelevant errors in inflating . so I suggest check them first

Comment: that's it ! I had a fooly  mistake in my item layout , thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem and my issue was that in my item layout I placed `<View>` element but without the capital V and the compiler didn't complain about that

```
 <view
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

**FYI**

> Java try block is used to enclose the code that might throw an
>   exception. So no need to create ***try-catch*** block here.

You can try with

```
View viewOBJ = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.faviorate_video_item, parent, false);
ViewHolder viewHolderOBJ = new ViewHolder(viewOBJ);
return viewHolderOBJ;
```

Comment: @user3422607 same problem ??

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Show line no with code .add string checking with `!= null`

Comment: @user3422607 add this in question section .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148672/discussion-between-user3422607-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 1):

Please remove try block. like below

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faviorate_video_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);


}
```

Comment: there was not that block at first  , and why should that solve ?